# Vue3 - Reactivity not working as expected

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

There something about Vue3 reactivity that I am not understanding...

```
<template>
  <Pagination v-model="params" />
</template>

import { defineComponent, reactive, computed } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Jobs'
  setup(){
    const store = useStore()
    const jobsParams = computed(() => store.getters['Jobs/getParams'])
    const params = reactive(jobsParams) // Should be reactive?

    return { params }
  }
})
```

I want to get `jobs` from the store and then 'copy' it to a reactive object called params that I can then manipulate based on a child component.

The error that I am getting when updating the value of params is:

```
Write operation failed: computed value is readonly
```

Why would I be getting this error when I am not manipulating those values?

If that is not the way to do this, how can I correctly pass a object to `Pagination`  and update the values accordingly?

Comment: did you try exporting jobs directly instead of making it reactive ?

Comment: Your question reminded me to configure that variables name. Its not jobs, its jobs params that includes how many pages, what page and current page (from laravel api).

No I did not as that would be counter to how Vuex is supposed to be used?